# How to create category attribute programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I am workign on custom extension for **magento 2** and i need to create category attribute programmatically,

**List me exact steps, because i am not sure is the code to be placed in InstallData.php or where?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Magento 2.1 and upper Version, You can also refer blog for create attribute programmatically in detais by, [Create Custom category attribute in Magento 2](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-category-attribute-programmatically-in-magento-2/), [link to official docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html)

You have to just below code inside

**`For Magento Version 2.1.*`**

**app/code/{Packagename}/{Modulename}/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace {Packagename}\{Modulename}\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory; 

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
    * Category setup factory
    *
    * @var CategorySetupFactory
    */
    private $categorySetupFactory;
    /**
    * Init
    *
    * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
         $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 
            'custom_attribute', 
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
             ]
         );
         $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**app/code/{Packagename}/{Modulename}/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general"> 
        <field name="custom_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Attribute Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>  
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**This is older version of Magento,**

For **Magento Version 2.0.***

Set category attribute like below,

**`app/code/Vendor/Categoryattr/Setup/InstallData.php`** file,

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
    
namespace Vendor\CategoryAttribute\Setup;
    
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    
    
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory; 

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
     
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */ 
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'custom_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

remove `var/generation` folder and run command,

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade** to working inside category.

Comment: Try this code, but not created attribute.

Comment: have you checked inside database eav_attribute table, your attribute is generate or not?

Comment: Yes checked in database table, but attribute isn't created :(

Comment: plz add your full code to here show we can checked inside code, this is working code, with registration.php file

Comment: I have updated my code, please check

Comment: Made some changes, I have edited the answer and it worked. Thank you Rakesh for help.

Comment: thanks for the code, I got `custom_attribute` in my `eav_attribute` table but how I can display this field in backend of category?

Comment: @RiyasMuhammed ... are you using 2.1.x?

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.1.x

Comment: I know for a fact that Rakesh knows what he is doing and that is is prob right but WHY does the devdocs of magento still give the old method then??  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, I have done the same category attribute is created but it's value not saved inside database and also not create attribute inside database ..

Comment: I have created the custom catalog attribute value and the value is saved in db. But how can I access this attribute value of rach cattegory in my observer?

Comment: cant create category attribute store wise http://prntscr.com/juwcge

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, how to make this attribute available in this Api response, /V1/categories/list

Answer (score 7):

As of **magento 2.1**  you will also need to create a UI components before the field will show up in admin.

Create:

> app/code/Vendor/Categoryattr/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <fieldset name="custom_tab">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Tab Name</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">12</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="custom_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using below code you can add category attribute:

In your module create Setup folder , inside it create file **InstallData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Ibnab\CustomAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
         $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
         $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute',
    );
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute', [
             'type' => 'int',
             'label' => 'My Atrribute ',
             'input' => 'select',
             'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
             'required' => false,
             'sort_order' => 100,
             'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
             'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );
    $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
    $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        $idg,
        'my_attribute',
        46
    );
$installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesn't seem to be working. We need to make text are attribute.

Comment: Can you please add code what you have tried?

Comment: Please check my code

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The attribute not create and not display in admin.

Answer (score 1):

Good references above. This one worked well for me to create an attribute for a category. I've tested that on v2.0.6.

It should be placed in app/code/Vendor/Extension/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'custom_attribute',
            [
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

In my blog I wrote a complete example how to do so http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento2-create-custom-category-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        //Category Attribute Create Script
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'myattributecode' => [
                 'type' => 'varchar',
                 'label' => 'Attribute Title',
                 'input' => 'textarea',
                 'required' => false,
                 'sort_order' => 100,
                 'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                 'group' => 'General Information',
                 'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                 'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                 'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                 'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```